# Php loop with json coming back empty

Tags: php, json, for-loop

what am i doing wrong here?

when i have only One result coming back this code works perfectly

```
$someObject = json_decode($data);
$id=$someObject->clips[0]->id;
```

but when i want to do a loop because i may get back 10 results this code is not working,  i am sure i am missing something very simple here

```
$someObject = json_decode($data);
//var_dump($someObject);

foreach($someObject as $json){
   echo $json->clips[0]->id; 
}
```

EDIT:
this solution worked for anyone else who comes looking

```
foreach ($someObject->clips as $clip){
   echo $clip->id. "<br>";
 }
```

not sure how the other one answers the for loop issue i was having however.

Comment: Maybe `foreach ($someObject->clips as $clip) echo $clip->id;`? Can't say for sure without seeing the JSON. But that won't stop the hordes from throwing out guesses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: share json `$data` ?

Comment: i came here knowing how to extract it, not loop it. thanks ur answer however did help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
foreach($someObject as $json){
  echo $json->clips[0]->id; 
}
```

to

```
$i=0;
foreach($someObject as $json){
   echo $json->clips[$i]->id; 
   $i++;
}
```

or as miken32 stated in the comment

```
foreach ($someObject->clips as $clip){
 echo $clip->id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this index `[0]` to dynamic index.

```
foreach($someObject as $k => $json){
   echo $json->clips[$k]->id;  // Insert $k here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

read this reference: [control-structures.foreach.php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

in php array if you want to get all of items iterate you can use foreach

imaging you have this sample json:

```
{
  "clips": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "test",
          "tags": [
              "tag1",
              "tag2",
              "tag3"
          ]
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test2",
          "tags": [
              "tag4",
              "tag5",
              "tag6"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

if you want to get clips and tag list you can use this code:

```
<?php
$jsonText = '{"clips": [{"id": 1,"name": "test","tags": ["tag1","tag2","tag3"]},{"id": 2,"name": "test2","tags": ["tag4","tag5","tag6"]}]}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonText);

// in this loop you can get clipObject
foreach($jsonObj->clips as $clipObj){
    echo "clip id:" . $clipObj->id . "<br>\n";
    echo "clip name:" . $clipObj->name. "<br>\n";

    // in this loop you can get tags
    foreach($clipObj->tags as $tag){
        echo "clip tag:" . $tag. "<br>\n";
    }

}
```